# Git error: "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, bitbucket

Strange issue here. We keep getting a connection closed by remote host when all 48 of our servers try pulling from Git. When running the `.sh` file directly (which has git pull code), there is no issue, unless its run at the same time as the other pulls (`*/5` cron job).

Below is the `.sh` file run:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=master
BASE_DIR=/root/api
if [ ! -d $BASE_DIR ]; then
        mkdir -p $BASE_DIR
fi

cd $BASE_DIR

if [ ! -d .git ]; then
        git init
        git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:deximedia/api_nodejs.git
        git pull origin $BRANCH
    forever start $BASE_DIR/call/index.js
elif [[ $(git ls-remote origin -h refs/heads/master | awk '{ print $1 }') != $(git rev-list --max-count=1 master) ]]; then
                git pull origin $BRANCH
                forever stop $BASE_DIR/call/index.js
        forever start $BASE_DIR/call/index.js
fi
```

And below is the error we see when all servers try running the above .sh file:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: I have no answer to that, but some oddity that I observed with a Gitlab server is that it hung for unknown reason if I "push"ed commits that included larger (15 Mb) files via http protocol. However, with SSH it doesn't have any probs even with large files. And Github, for example works flawlessly on the same large file via SSH and https (all on the same machine, same data, same Git version)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem when our CI system tried to fetch several branches from a simple ssh git setup at basically the same time. I suspected there is some issue with the ssh server that cuts the connections.

For me, setting MaxStartups in /etc/ssh/sshd_config solved the problem. The default on our system was 10:30:60. Setting it to 100 disables the probabilistic approach and simply allows for 100 concurrent connection start-ups. Adjust as needed, based on the number of concurrent connection set-ups you'd like to have supported, e.g., the number of enabled build jobs in your CI that fetch from git concurrently through SSH.